# How to interpret the "condition && $var = value" syntax in php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am inspecting a wordpress theme code and I found this row of code:

```
840 <= $width && $sizes = '(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 1362px) 62vw, 840px';
```

What does this row mean in terms of php?

To be more clear, this is the whole function:

```
/**
 * Add custom image sizes attribute to enhance responsive image functionality
 * for content images
 *
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 *
 * @param string $sizes A source size value for use in a 'sizes' attribute.
 * @param array  $size  Image size. Accepts an array of width and height
 *                      values in pixels (in that order).
 * @return string A source size value for use in a content image 'sizes' attribute.
 */
function twentysixteen_content_image_sizes_attr( $sizes, $size ) {
    $width = $size[0];

    840 <= $width && $sizes = '(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 1362px) 62vw, 840px';

    if ( 'page' === get_post_type() ) {
        840 > $width && $sizes = '(max-width: ' . $width . 'px) 85vw, ' . $width . 'px';
    } else {
        840 > $width && 600 <= $width && $sizes = '(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 984px) 61vw, (max-width: 1362px) 45vw, 600px';
        600 > $width && $sizes = '(max-width: ' . $width . 'px) 85vw, ' . $width . 'px';
    }

    return $sizes;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This checks a condition and sets a variable in case it is true.

It is like saying:

```
conditionA && $variable="value";
```

In your case, it is like saying:

```
if (840 <= $width) {
    $sizes = '(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 1362px) 62vw, 840px';
}
```

See a little test:

```
<?php

$a=3;
$v=0;

echo "v = $v\n";

$a == 3 && $v = "hello";

echo "v = $v";
```

If you execute it you get:

```
v = 0
v = hello
```

Answer (score 0):

just like this:

```
840 <= $width && $sizes = '(max-width: 709px) 85vw, (max-width: 909px) 67vw, (max-width: 1362px) 62vw, 840px';
```

is

```
conditionA && conditionB
```

equal to

```
if( conditionA && conditionB ){}
```

or

```
if( conditionA ) { conditionB }
```

the same with

```
conditionA || conditionB
```

like

```
if( conditionA || conditionB ){}
```

for example

```
$a = 1;
$b = 0;

// if( $a == 2 && $b = 3 ){}
$a == 2 && $b = 3; // && do not exec $b = 3,becuase $a != 2
echo $a,' ',$b;  // 1 0

// if( $a == 1 && $b = 4 ){}
$a == 1 && $b = 4; // exec $b = 4,becuase $a == 1
echo $a,' ',$b; //  1 4
// if( $a == 1 && $b = 4 ){}

// and how about  || 
$a = 1;
$b = 0;

// if( $a == 1 || $b = 3 ){}
$a == 1 || $b = 3; // && do not exec $b = 3,becuase $a == 1
echo $a,' ',$b; //  1 0

// if( $a == 2 || $b = 4 ){}
$a == 2 || $b = 4; // exec $b = 4,becuase $a == 1 not 2
echo $a,' ',$b;  // 1 4
```

Comment: No. This is not `conditionA && conditionB` because the second block is an assignment.